# Excel macro to find cells with numbers larger than 20 in a specific column and then divide the matching cells by 1000

Tags: vba, excel

I have a number of log files that I am importing into Excel and I am trying to create a macro that can find numbers greater than 20 in a specific column then divide the cells that match the criteria by 1000 (converting from Kb to Mb).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Agree with @SiddharthRout

Comment: Rule #1 of programming: Write your own code.

Comment: +1 @SiddharthRout. Wish that option was still a valid (private) close button click!

Comment: @brettdj: See my comment [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085858/removing-text-around-a-number-using-vba) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your Kb values start in row 1 of column A, write this formula in column B :

```
=IF(A1>20, A1/1000, A1)
```

Basically, what this does, is tell the computer that if A1 is greater than 20, put A1/1000 in this cell, otherwise put A1. Stretching this formula down the column will give you the right formula for each row.

Comment: Thanks Bernard, that was exactly what I needed to do.  Much simpler than a Macro!

Answer (score 1):

Macro Version .. if u have data in A column

```
Sub test()
Dim erange As Range
Dim lrow As long

With ActiveSheet
lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each erange In .Range("A2:A" & lrow)

If erange.Value > 20 Then

erange.Offset(0, 1).Value = erange.Value / 1000

End If

Next erange

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim lrow As Integer` I would recommend changing `Integer` to `Long`

Comment: + 1 for an alternative excel solution :)

Comment: Eagle eye . Updated - Sid :)

Comment: There is one other thing as well but then that will be too much :D... would rather give you the [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) I am referring to the `DOT` before `Rows.Count`

Comment: Just written above code in notepad :D -Again Updated ..thanks Sid